# Magento How to Add custom SM super categories

Tags: php, magento

I'm Using Magneto CMS, and I want to add a custom Super category like the following screenshot.
the screenshot shows a product in my site and its super category (Favorite and Quick view)

[image]

Actually I can disable any one of them, add another from the provided super categories allowed by the theme but I want to add my custom one

Comment: FYI, Magento has its [own StackExchange site](http://magento.stackexchange.com). I recommend removing your question from this website and posting it there. Do not post there without removing this question first as [cross-posting is prohibited](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add your custom one just find the glyphicon icon of the category you are looking for and replace it by your own glyphicon . Just inspect the site and get to the source of the image and replace it.

Comment: Thanks for your response,
I think your solution will add just an icon .
I want to add an icon to link a page or action

Comment: then in the  botton  provide the link url . I dont think u will have problem in finding th button if u do please tell